# Composer problem install verify-email-bundle Symfony 5.2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

i cant add bundle, and i need for confirmation email register use

composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle

```
  Problem 1
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle is locked to version 3.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.0.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/orm is locked to version 2.7.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/orm 2.7.4 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/orm 2.7.4 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.4.0 requires doctrine/orm ^2.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[2.7.4].
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle is locked to version 3.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
PS C:\Projecto\Symfony\Symfony5\xxx>
```

Exception:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Security\EmailVerifier": argument "$helper" of method "__construct()" has type "SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\VerifyEmailHelperInterface" but this class was not found.
```

App\Security\EmailVerifier.php

namespace App\Security;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\VerifyEmailHelperInterface;

class EmailVerifier
{
    private $verifyEmailHelper;
    private $mailer;
    private $entityManager;

public function __construct(VerifyEmailHelperInterface $helper, MailerInterface $mailer, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    $this->verifyEmailHelper = $helper;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->entityManager = $manager;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is in no way related to `symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle` - just read the message: you are requiring `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` in your configuration, and you are using PHP 8. This Doctrine bundle has not been made compatible with PHP 8 yet, as `doctrine/migrations` is not compatible with PHP 8.

You either need to remove these packages, or downgrade to PHP 7

Comment: Is this still updated?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when symfony/mailer is not installed

```
composer require symfony/mailer
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should `symfony/mailer` contain a class from the namespace `SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail`? Or why should it resolve the given error messages thrown by Composer complaining about the wrong PHP version?

Comment: This solution worked for me in PHP 8.2 with Symfony 6.1. I was receiving this exception:

`Cannot autowire service "App\Security\EmailVerifier": argument "$mailer" of method "__construct()" has type "Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface" but this class was not found.`

Answer (score -1):

Try this bundle, this will resolve the issue.

```
composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle
```

if you already installed it, then check `config/bundles.php` file that it's declared there. If not, add this code line

```
SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\SymfonyCastsVerifyEmailBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. According to the question, that's the exact command that was already used. What makes you think that running it once more magically resolves the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase
My bad, my answer was incomplete. Please check now.

Answer (score -2):

You juste have to install symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle

run *composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle*

Comment: That looks pretty strange to me - that is exactly the command that is used, and that exact command throws the given error